# Permissibility around working for an asset management company

Tags: halal-haram

Salam

I got a job offer from a [company](https://www.oaktreecapital.com/) which is in the asset management space. My job will be in the IT department and I won't be involved in any of the financial side of company.

I am not a financial guy so I have no idea what the company makes most of its money from. However using chatGPT it looks like they make money via issuing loans and also trading high yield bonds which sounds problematic from the get go.

Looking to get some guidance on wether or not it would be permissible to work for such a company

Would it be permissible to work for such a company